# Unit testing an AsyncResult in celery

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, celery

I am trying to test some celery functionality in Django's unit testing framework, but whenever I try to check an AsyncResult the tests act like it was never started.

I know this code works in a real environment with RabbitMQ, so I was just wondering why it didn't work when using the testing framework.

Here is an example:

```
@override_settings(CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True,
                   CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True,
                   BROKER_BACKEND = 'memory',)
def test_celery_do_work(self):
    result = myapp.tasks.celery_do_work.AsyncResult('blat')
    applied_task = myapp.tasks.celery_do_work.apply_async((), task_id='blat')
    applied_task.wait()
    # THIS SUCCEEDS
    self.assertTrue(applied_task.successful())
    # THIS FAILS
    self.assertTrue(result.successful())
```

Does using the ALWAYS_EAGER option disable the AsyncResult functionality since it's executing immediately? If so, is there any way to able to unit test AsyncResult status checking? If I try to take out the ALWAYS_EAGER option the tests never run, so I am at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` is `True`, the call to `apply_async()` is actually replaced with `apply()`. The result returned is an `EagerResult`, which already contains the result of your task.

So, yes, setting `ALWAYS_EAGER = True` disables the entire `AsyncResult` functionnality. The entire async process is bypassed, and no task is actually sent to the broker, which is why you cannot retrieve the result through an `AsyncResult`.

Use `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` when you are testing code path which just need a Celery result, and work the same way with an `EagerResult` or an `AsyncResult`.

If needed, there is a way to run tests with `AsyncResult` too, with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`, but for this, you'll need to start a worker before calling the task in your test case. The worker will then be able to execute your task, and `AsyncResult` will work just fine. You can take a look at [django-celery-testworker](https://github.com/RentMethod/django-celery-testworker) which seems to do just that, although I've not tested it.

Comment: I figured it was probably something like that, but didn't know about the EagerResult object. I thought they were always going to be AsyncResults. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43648921/1617295) for starting workers from the unit test itself.