# How to test code that creates Celery tasks?

Tags: python, django, celery

I've read [Testing with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html) but I'm still a bit confused. I want to test code that generates a Celery task by running the task manually and explicitly, something like:

```
def test_something(self):
    do_something_that_generates_a_celery_task()
    assert_state_before_task_runs()
    run_task()
    assert_state_after_task_runs()
```

I don't want to entirely mock up the creation of the task but at the same time I don't care about testing the task being picked up by a Celery worker. I'm assuming Celery works.

The actual context in which I'm trying to do this is a Django application where there's some code that takes too long to run in a request, so, it's delegated to background jobs.

Comment: you could mock:
`do_something_that_generates_a_celery_task()`

and add a `side_effect()` which calls the the function that the celery task would invoke. if the celery task is a function, then you can easily run outside of celery

Comment: @UkuLoskit: I don't want to want to mock it. I'm not sure I can mock it. It's a selenium script that interacts with the testing web server.

Comment: This is related but I haven't managed to get it to work yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233680/in-memory-broker-for-celery-unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

In test mode use [`CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER` = `True`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager).  You can set this setting in your `settings.py` in django if you have followed the default guide for django-celery configuration.

Comment: That would have two issues: 1) the http request would fail if the task takes too long, which is possible as it's the reason I'm using celery for and 2) it wouldn't let me assert the state of the system before the task is being done; which I want to do to make sure the user experience is good when tasks are not being picked up quickly.